# How can I convert this to use a java stream?

Tags: java

I have this method that will return an integer array of all the values in a specific position of all the enum values. I'm wondering how I can convert this to a stream to make it shorter and more efficient.

So that method returns an integer array containing 12, 16, 19, 15 but I'm wondering how I can shorten it with a stream.

Thanks!

```
ITEM_1(12),
ITEM_3(16),
ITEM_4(19),
ITEM_5(15);

private final int ITEM_ID;

ENUM_NAME(int item_id) {
    this.ITEM_ID = item_id;
}

public int[] getIDs() {
    final ENUM_NAME[] enum_name = ENUM_NAME.values();
    final int[] item_ids = new int[enum_name.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < enum_name.length; i++) {
        item_ids[i] = enum_name[i].getItemID();
    }

    return item_ids;
}
```

Comment: "shorter" doesn't mean "more efficient". Anyway one way to improve performance is to cache `values()` since it creates each time you call it new array with enum values. OR cache `int[]` array and simply copy it to new one when you are calling `getIDs`. But to be honest I am not sure why you even need `getIDs` method. How are you going to use these IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten looping through values with something like this:

```
Arrays.stream(ENUM_NAME.values()).map(t -> t.ITEM_ID)
```

It will create Stream with ITEM_ID values (values will be of type Integer)

To return int array (int[]), like getIDs() method in your code, use:

```
Arrays.stream(ENUM_NAME.values()).mapToInt(t -> t.ITEM_ID).toArray()
```

Comment: If you want `IntStream` then you need `mapToInt`. Also you need to call `toArray` to get `int[]` which OP is asking.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it! :)